# Need assistance in Joining 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I need to join 2 tables and assign 0 (HoursBilled column) and all Months appeared in the BilledHours table for each unique AuthId.

First table (**AuthHours**) has data of each ClientId and their allowed hours (per month) for different date ranges per unique AuthId.

```
create table AuthHours
(AuthId INT, ClientId INT, AuthStartDate DATE, AuthEndDate DATE, AllowedHoursPerMonth Float);

INSERT INTO AuthHours
VALUES
(123, 55, '2021-12-19', '2022-03-17', 43.0),
(109, 55, '2021-12-19', '2022-03-17', 9.0),
(218, 55, '2021-12-19', '2022-03-17', 6.0),
(619, 55, '2021-12-19', '2022-03-17', 43.0),
(777, 55, '2021-12-19', '2022-03-17', 43.0),
(345, 55, '2022-03-18', '2022-07-28', 40.0),
(346, 55, '2022-03-18', '2022-07-28', 12.0),
(395, 55, '2022-03-18', '2022-07-28', 10.0),
(487, 55, '2022-03-18', '2022-07-28', 45.0),
(198, 55, '2022-03-18', '2022-07-28', 37.0)

SELECT * FROM AuthHours
```

Second table (**BilledHours**) (*already grouped by ClientId, AuthId, Month and Year*) has data of each ClientId and their **already** billed hours per AuthId and Month.

```
create table BilledHours
(ClientId INT, Month VARCHAR(10), Year INT, AuthId INT, HoursBilled Float);

INSERT INTO BilledHours
VALUES
(55, 'January', 2022, 123, 26.33),
(55, 'January', 2022, 109, 4.25),
(55, 'January', 2022, 777, 2.5),
(55, 'February', 2022, 123, 32.5),
(55, 'February', 2022, 109, 4.25),
(55, 'February', 2022, 777, 1.5)

SELECT * FROM BilledHours
```

**I need to assign 0 HoursBilled for each AuthId that not in the BilledHours table, but if TODAY Date not between AuthStartDate and AuthEndDate date ranges, keep it NULL. Also, Month and Year appeared in the BilledHours table need to be added for each AuthId that not in the BilledHours table.**

My Join, but it's wrong (obviously).

```
SELECT  AuthHours.AuthId,
        AuthHours.ClientId,
        AuthHours.AuthStartDate,
        AuthHours.AuthEndDate,
        BilledHours.Month,
        BilledHours.Year,
        AuthHours.AllowedHoursPerMonth,
        BilledHours.HoursBilled
        
FROM AuthHours
LEFT JOIN BilledHours
  ON (AuthHours.AuthId = BilledHours.AuthId) AND (AuthHours.ClientId = BilledHours.ClientId)
```

Incorrect output:

| AuthId | ClientId | AuthStartDate | AuthEndDate | Month | Year | AllowedHoursPerMonth | HoursBilled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 55 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | January | 2022 | 43 | 26.33 |
| 123 | 55 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | February | 2022 | 43 | 32.5 |
| 109 | 55 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | January | 2022 | 9 | 4.25 |
| 109 | 55 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | February | 2022 | 9 | 4.25 |
| 218 | 55 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | **NULL** | **NULL** | 6 | **NULL** |
| 619 | 55 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | **NULL** | **NULL** | 43 | **NULL** |
| 777 | 55 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | January | 2022 | 43 | 2.5 |
| 777 | 55 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | February | 2022 | 43 | 1.5 |
| 345 | 55 | 2022-03-18 | 2022-07-28 | NULL | NULL | 40 | NULL |
| 346 | 55 | 2022-03-18 | 2022-07-28 | NULL | NULL | 12 | NULL |
| 395 | 55 | 2022-03-18 | 2022-07-28 | NULL | NULL | 10 | NULL |
| 487 | 55 | 2022-03-18 | 2022-07-28 | NULL | NULL | 45 | NULL |
| 198 | 55 | 2022-03-18 | 2022-07-28 | NULL | NULL | 37 | NULL |

Output I need:

| AuthId | ClientId | AuthStartDate | AuthEndDate | Month | Year | AllowedHoursPerMonth | HoursBilled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 55 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | January | 2022 | 43 | 26.33 |
| 123 | 55 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | February | 2022 | 43 | 32.5 |
| 109 | 55 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | January | 2022 | 9 | 4.25 |
| 109 | 55 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | February | 2022 | 9 | 4.25 |
| 218 | 55 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | **January** | **2022** | 6 | **0** |
| 218 | 55 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | **February** | **2022** | 6 | **0** |
| 619 | 55 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | **January** | **2022** | 43 | **0** |
| 619 | 55 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | **February** | **2022** | 43 | **0** |
| 777 | 55 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | January | 2022 | 43 | 2.5 |
| 777 | 55 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | February | 2022 | 43 | 1.5 |
| 345 | 55 | 2022-03-18 | 2022-07-28 | *NULL* | *NULL* | 40 | *NULL* |
| 346 | 55 | 2022-03-18 | 2022-07-28 | *NULL* | *NULL* | 12 | *NULL* |
| 395 | 55 | 2022-03-18 | 2022-07-28 | *NULL* | *NULL* | 10 | *NULL* |
| 487 | 55 | 2022-03-18 | 2022-07-28 | *NULL* | *NULL* | 45 | *NULL* |
| 198 | 55 | 2022-03-18 | 2022-07-28 | *NULL* | *NULL* | 37 | *NULL* |

Comment: Can you explain why you're expecting AuthId 218 & 619 to have rows for Jan/Feb but 345,346 etc you're not?

Comment: Because 218 and 619 Auths COULD have billable hours but they DIDN'T. This particular client (55) has authorization for them for 2021-12-19 and 2022-03-17 date range.
345,346 etc Auths will be in the future (2022-03-18 and 2022-07-28 date ranges). Hope it make sense.

Comment: No it's not clear, all have a AuthStartDate prior to now() and all have a AuthEndDate  in the future....?

Comment: For example: AuthId 218 (unique) has authorization to use specific code from 2021-12-19 to 2022-03-17. So technically, Client (55) allow to use 6 hours every month in the date range I mentioned, but by some reason Client didn't use it, so for this AuthId (218) Client used 0 hours out of 6 in January and February (I llimited data for 2022 only). I need to represent it in the joined table.  AuthId (345) will be available starting 2022-03-18. Since today is 2022-02-24 it is not possible to use it yet, that is why it needs to be NULL in this case.

Comment: If you routinely need to populate the billed table with multiple missing months, a calendar table would probably come in handy.

Comment: This seems to be basically the same as your previous question. In your previous question you get all the relevant month/year combinations, so just join that onto your data from this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the query to reflect more what you are looking for with the month/year request

```
select
    distinct
    a.authid,
    a.clientid,
    a.authstartdate,
    a.authenddate,
    case when a.hoursbilled is null then null else a.month end as month,
    case when a.hoursbilled is null then null else a.year end as year,
    a.allowedhourspermonth,
    a.hoursbilled
from 
    (
        select
        a.authid,
        a.clientid,
        a.authstartdate,
        a.authenddate,
        a.allowedhourspermonth,
        a.month,
        a.year,
        case 
            when a.hoursbilled is null and getdate() between cast(a.authstartdate as date) and cast(a.authenddate as date) then 0
            when a.hoursbilled is null and getdate() not between cast(a.authstartdate as date) and cast(a.authenddate as date) then null
            else a.hoursbilled 
        end as hoursbilled
    from 
        (
        SELECT 
            a.authid,
            a.clientid,
            a.authstartdate,
            a.authenddate,
            a.allowedhourspermonth,
            b.month,
            b.year,
            b.hoursbilled
        FROM 
            (
            select
                d.clientid,
                d.month,
                d.year,
                d.authid,
                b.hoursbilled
            from 
                (
                    select
                        distinct
                        a.clientid,
                        a.authid,
                        month,
                        year
                    from BilledHours b 
                        join AuthHours a on 1=1
                ) d 
                left join BilledHours b on b.authid = d.authid and d.clientid = b.clientid and d.month = b.month and b.year = d.year
            ) b 
                left join AuthHours a on a.clientid = b.clientid and a.authid = b.authid
        ) a
    ) a
```

This is an option without a CAL_DM table, but I would recommend investing in a CAL_DM table if your company does not have one already.

Comment: Thank You, but that's not what I wanted.

Comment: How is this different than what you needed?

Comment: I provided output I need. Month and Year should be also present in the joined table. You only converted NULL to 0. But thank you

Comment: You may have included that in your example table, but you did not ask for that in the question. If you take out the month/year columns provided from my results you should have a perfect match correct? If you have additional logic for the month/year I would happy to look at that as well

Comment: You are correct, I had to specify it in the question, I will edit it. But at the same time I have to group by month and year.

Comment: I updated the query to reflect what you are looking for

Comment: Hi, @ArchAngelPwn. Is it possible to develop same logic without using CTE? I need to create a dynamic report in Tableau, however (unfortunately) Tableau is not supporting CTE. Thank You.

Comment: Yes, I remember when I started with tableau queries running into the same problem, give me a minute and I'll edit the code to be usable by customer Tableau queries

Comment: @Yara1994 I made the change that should be usable in Tableau. From what I remember is that when you are using tableau you can just use a nested from statement. So essentially it is a CTE in the other direction (moving up through a from instead of down from a CTE)